# ActionMailer Errno::ENOEXEC Windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows-8, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a problem with my ActionMailer. I try to configure it in local to use with Windows 8.
My problem is that I have this error :

```
Errno::ENOEXEC in Devise::PasswordsController#create
Exec format error - /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -f "no-replay@example.com" -- "mail@gmail.com"
```

Here my ActionMailer config:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  arguments: '-i -t'
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-replay@example.com'}
```

I don't know if on Windows 8 I have a special path to do that and if yes, which arguments do I have to set ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sendmail is a linux utility to send emails. It is not available on windows, hence No Executable Found error. I just learned about ActionMailer 30 minutes ago, but the way I understand it actionmailer cannot send emails by itself, it needs a utility or server to do that